# Watermark on document image or custom boxes

Tags: backgrounds, watermark, xwatermark, draftwatermark

I have added water mark using `\backgroundsetup`

```
\backgroundsetup{
angle=45,
scale=1,contents={\includegraphics[allpages,
    ]{water_mark.png}}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}\tcbset{colback=blue!8!white,colframe=blue!25!white, boxrule=0pt, left=10pt,right=10pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}

\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{verbatim} texts in box\end{verbatim} \end{tcolorbox}
```

This what I have achieved:

[image: This what i have achieved]

I am happy to see the watermark in every page but the problem is that some pages have images and custom boxes, in such pages the watermark is below that images and boxes. I want the watermark above the image or box.

Comment: Please show us what you have done to achieve this box (MWE).

Comment: And why do you use the latex3 tag? Do you have some expl3 functions relevant to this issue? In addition: Do you really use two different packages for watermarks?

Comment: Have highlighted the code used and the screenshot of my out put. Please see my edits

Comment: That does not help. We need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1) to really help you.

Comment: @Muhamed, @TeXnician refers to put a _minimal_ compilable code that begins with `\documentclass{...}`, ends with `\end{document}` and include the necessary packages to produce your showed result.

Comment: Can u check my edits, have added few more codes used, tcolorbox used draw the rectangle box

Comment: That's still not compilable... It would be very helpful if you could follow the link I've provided and help us help you by post a minimal compilable code snippet (with documentclass, *necessary* packages and the document environment with minimal content).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `background` package, you could use `xwatermark`.

Its starred (*) variant of `\newwatermark` command puts the watermark in the foreground instead of the
background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=blue!8!white,colframe=blue!25!white, boxrule=0pt, left=10pt,right=10pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt, arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt}

\usepackage{mwe}% for test purpose only, you don't need to use this in your document

\begin{document}

\newwatermark*[angle=45,scale=1,xpos=0,ypos=40, allpages]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=10cm]{example-image}}% put your image here with the correct height and width

\section{An example of section}

\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{verbatim} 
texts in box
\end{verbatim} 
\end{tcolorbox}

\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]